# Web Scraping without formatting with rvest on R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to get a lyric song from an website through R and my text is getting all together.

```
library(rvest)    
url <- "https://www.letras.mus.br/lily-allen/fuck-you"
datatest <- read_html(url)
b <- datatest %>%
  html_node("article") %>%
  html_text()
b
```

I wanted to have the text with at least a space between differents paragraphs/words, it could even be one big vector with all the words.
I need this formatting so I can count the amount of times each word was mentioned through different songs, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Perhaps `library(stringr);datatest %>% html_node("article") %>% str_extract_all(., "(?<=\\>)[^<\n]+") %>% .[[1]] %>% paste(., collapse=". ")`

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separe between paragraph if you only need to count the amount of times each word was mentioned through different songs.

First, I recommend you to put all the words to lower and then count the words, so try this:

```
> require(stringr)
> b<-tolower(b)
> str_count(b,"fuck")
[1] 28
```

If you think this doesn't work with unseparated words:

```
> str_count("fuckfuck","fuck")
[1] 2
```

Comment: Isn't it counting "fuckfuck" as one word? I need that in the line "str_count("fuckfuck","fuck")" it counts as 3 repetitions of the word, that's why I was trying to separate.

Comment: Hi Myst, the first parameter ("fuckfuck") must be your vector "b", and the second paramter the word that you want to count. In this example despite of "fuckfuck" is one word, It has twice "fuck" and returnts effectively 2. So you don't need separe it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr` to get the sentences between the `>` and `<` and then `paste` it together

```
library(stringr)
datatest %>% 
     html_node("article") %>%
     str_extract_all(., "(?<=\\>)[^<\n]+") %>% 
     .[[1]] %>%
      paste(., collapse=". ")
```